# grav cms : twig extension to include php file

Tags: php, twig, twig-extension, grav

I have created a twig extension in grav cms I have respected the structure that I is listed in the documentation but it dosen't work. the function that I'm using in my template doesn't appear in my source code when I execute it

*here is my code:*

```
<?php
namespace Grav\Plugin;
class PhpIncludeTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'PhpIncludeTwigExtension';
    }
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('includeFile', [$this, 'exampleFunction'])
        ];
    }
    public function exampleFunction(string $file)
    {
        ob_start();
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'./'.$file);
        $content = ob_get_clean();

        return $content;   
    }
}
```

here is my template :

```
<div class="blog-home1 spacer bg-light" id="actualites">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                            <!-- Column -->
                            <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
                                <h2 class="title h2 h2_color">Actualités du Digital Learning</h2>
                                <h3 class="subtitle h6">Les actualités sont extraites du site Digital Learning Academy</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="actuListing" class="row m-t-40">
                            <!--
                                This h4 is add to fix SEO
                            --> 

                           <h4 class="fix">Les actualités sont extraites du site Digital Learning Academy</h4>

                        {{ includeFile('./../../getData.php') }}


                    </div>

                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                            <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
                                <h6 class="subtitle">Nous remercions particulièrement le site Digital Learning Academy by IL&DI <br>et Philippe Lacroix</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is this actually a different question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60376583/grav-cms-create-twig-extension-not-working where you posted exactly the same PHP code which doesn't work?

Comment: the file that im include called includeFile not execute and this file has a function return a code html i want to append it to my template